# I haven't seen her "for"/"in" two days

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, formality, dialects

What's the difference between using either **for** or **in** in the following examples?

> *Bill hasn't taken a vacation **for/in two years***.
>
> *Jack hasn't been to school **for/in four days***.
>
> *I hadn't seen Mary **for/in three weeks** when she finally decided to show up*.

[NgramAmEng](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seen+her+for+two+months%2Cseen+her+in+two+months%2Cseen+her+for+a+year%2Cseen+her+in+a+year%2Cseen+her+in+a+week%2Cseen+her+for+a+week&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20for%20two%20months%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20in%20two%20months%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20for%20a%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20in%20a%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20in%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20for%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0) vs. [Ngram BrEng](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seen+her+for+two+months%2Cseen+her+in+two+months%2Cseen+her+for+a+year%2Cseen+her+in+a+year%2Cseen+her+in+a+week%2Cseen+her+for+a+week&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20for%20two%20months%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20for%20a%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen%20her%20for%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0)

> **IN**
>
> Expressing a period of time during which an event takes place or a situation remains the case:
>
> *they met in 1885*
>
> *at one o’clock in the morning*
>
> ***I hadn’t seen him in years***

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/in)

> **FOR**
>
> Indicating the length of (a period of time):
>
> *he was in prison for 12 years*
>
> ***I haven’t seen him for some time***

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/for)

Comment: No difference if the expression with ***in***  is understood to mean *in ( the last, those, - or whatever period in time you are referring to) two years.*

Comment: I don't think there's any *semantic* difference, and in most context they're interchangeable (though I'm sure ***for*** is far more common). But for reasons that escape me, I wouldn't be likely to use ***in*** in the following exchange: *"Have you ever been a smoker?", "Yes, but not **for** years"*.

Comment: (apparently [neither are other people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+for+years+now%2Cnot+in+years+now&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20for%20years%20now%3B%2Cc0) likely to use ***in*** there.)

Comment: You could also ask: "Why can't we say *I have been away in  five days*?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A We've had quite enough of negative-polarity items with the weather, thank you. / '... been away for 3 years' changes meaning between 'He hasn't been away for 3 years' and 'He's been away for 3 years'.

Comment: I believe this is a good question and I am looking forward to seeing a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I think i completed the work in five days is natural but do you think that I completed the work for five days is  correct

Comment: I'd never use it ('I spent five days completing the work'). I'd almost certainly mark the  construction wrong in an essay. But then as a maths teacher, I didn't mark many essays. In an A-Level maths paper ... I'd have to ask at a moderators['] meeting whether this constituted a reason to dock a mark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the difference between using either *for* or *in* in the following examples?
>
> - *Bill hasn't taken a vacation for/in two years.*
> - *Jack hasn't been to school for/in four days.*
> - *I hadn't seen Mary for/in three weeks when she finally decided to show up.*

There is no difference in grammaticality. All 3 sentences are grammatical, with either *for* or *in*.

There is no difference in meaning. All 3 sentences describe the same situation, with either *for* or *in*.

However, there **is** one difference in syntactic affordances. *In* with an indefinite durative temporal phrase (*in weeks, in two days, in donkey's years, in a long time,* etc.) is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/NPIs.pdf).
I.e, *in two days* is restricted to negative contexts, while *for two days* has no such restriction.

Notice that all the examples above are negative. Remove the -*n't* to see the difference.

*For* works fine, though the sentences don't mean the same thing.

- *Bill has taken a vacation **for** two years.* (a very long vacation)
- *Jack has been to school **for** four days.* (there were four daily attendances)
- *I had seen Mary **for** three weeks.* (indicates frequent or continuous contact)

But all the ones with *in* are ungrammatical, and have no discernible meaning.
Grammarians mark ungrammatical sentences with an asterisk:

- **Jack has been to school in four days.*
- **Bill has taken a vacation in two years.*
- **I had seen Mary in three weeks.*

In other words, in negative sentences, there are two ways to refer to duration, with *in* or with *for*.  Outside a negative context, the system doesn't work the same way. [Negation](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is very complex.

Comment: "In" can be sometimes be used with positive polarity. E.g. (future tense) "Jack will return to school *in* two days". Note that this has a different meaning to "Jack will return to school *for* two days".

Comment: "_**In** with an indefinite durative temporal phrase is a Negative Polarity Item._" What exactly is an _indefinite_ temporal phrase? In what sense is _two days_ an indefinite interval?

Comment: Which two days? That's not a description of some definite length of time, but rather just its size, which will fit anywhere in a linked set of days; it's indefinite. _Temporal_ means it's a phrase about time. _Durative_ means it's a phrase about a length of time, not an instant of time.

Comment: No grammar book says that `in` can be used in a negative context. Using `in` should be informal and grammatically incorrect.

Comment: There you go, then.

Answer (score 2):

This use of 'in' means '[with]in' (during) the time period, as opposed to 'in' (after) the time period.  Since time is never the recipient of anything, 'for' can be overloaded to mean 'during', and 'to' was once overloaded to mean '[un]to' which meant 'until'.

Answer (score 2):

My sense of the language insists there is a potential semantic difference, a difference in meaning, although the two phrases 'in two years' and 'for two years' are often *used* interchangably. Leveraging the difference in meaning might require nuanced poetic use, but I think not. For past tense, negative constructions (as in "Bill hasn't taken a vacation *in/for* two years"),

- '... in two years' means '**at any time during** the past two years';
- '... for two years' means '**since sometime prior to** the past two years'.

Comment: In the company I work for, we include credit card points information on customer's bills. This information is exported from our loyalty system and loaded before invoice production. It should not be done too early nor too late, otherwise the data will be either too old or not reflected on the bills. I wrote a program that runs on each bill cycle day and checks whether the data was loaded one or two days ago, or it sends an email alarm. Which phrase should I put in it? “Alarm: Credit points data have not been loaded _in/for_ (the past) two days.”

Comment: @YangMuye, disambiguating the two statements: "Credit points data have not been loaded *during* (=*in*) the past two days" or "Credit points data *earned during* (=*for*) the past two days have not been loaded". Note the phrase reordering. In sum, the statement "Credit points data have not been loaded *in* the past two days" says nothing about when the points were earned, while "Credit points data have not been loaded *for* the past two days" is ambiguous: it may be taken to refer only to points earned during the past two days, or it may be taken in the same sense as *in*. If that matters....